# Browser not opening in watir webdriver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I tried to launch "firefox" and "chrome browser" using `watir-webdriver`, but nothing even for 20 minutes.

I tried:

`Watir::Browser.new :firefox`

I am using
`Jruby`
`Watir - 0.6.11`
`Firefox - 33`

Comment: Those are the latest versions of watir-webdriver and FF, so it might be related to jruby.  What version of jruby are you running?

Comment: I think this statement `Watir::Browser.new :firefox` is not enough to launch browser window. Show more of what you are trying to do and where you are instantiating the browser variable.